# WCF NET TCP Service listening to thousands of remote computers

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

We have a NET TCP WCF service host running on a windows service getting thousands of messages per minute.

What WCF parameters should we consider changing when moving from getting all the messages from few computers, to getting all the messages from the various source computers directly?

```
Current:   3 computers --> WCF service

Propose:   5000 computers --> WCF service
```

Overall load is the same on both cases ~ 30,000 messages/min

Comment: Eventually we kept the same WCF parameters and saw that when messages are coming from much more client machines, load is better distributed on the server and overall server performance was better, when compared to having the same load of incoming messages coming from only few client machines.